# Checking whether every list in a list is null in Common Lisp

Tags: null, lisp, lambda, common-lisp, c++

I know that I can check whether a list of lists only contains null lists like this

```
CL-USER> (null (find-if (lambda (item) (not (null item))) my-list))
```

where `my-list` is a list of lists.

For example:

```
CL-USER> (null (find-if (lambda (item) (not (null item))) '(nil (bob) nil)))
NIL
CL-USER> (null (find-if (lambda (item) (not (null item))) '(() () ())))
T
```

But isn't there a shorter, easier way of doing this in Lisp?  If so, how?

Comment: EVERY is the right answer, but your examples would also be simpler as (find-if (complement #'null) my-list).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The higher order function `every` takes a predicate function and a list and returns true iff the predicate returns true for every element in the list.

So you can just do:

```
(every #'null my-list)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Strangely enough, Winston & Horn doesn't mention every.

Answer (score 1):

```
(find-if #'identity list)

(not (find-if-not #'null list))
```

Consult the Common Lisp HyperSpec for the full list of functions for lists and sequences.